# MaterialUI Custom Hover Style

Tags: reactjs, styles

I'm a newbie here to React and I'm a little bit confused on how to override classes in Material UI. I took a look at the examples and tried to mimic it but it didn't seem to do what I want it to do.

Basically, on a table row hover, I want to make it set a background color different from what it is currently doing.

Here is my approach:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 1020
  },
  tableWrapper: {
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  hover: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(7, 177, 77, 0.42)'
    }
  }
});

return <TableRow hover classes={{hover: classes.hover}} role="checkbox" aria-checked={isSelected} tabIndex={-1} key={n.row_id} selected={isSelected}>
     {this.insertRow(n, isSelected, counter, checkbox)}
```

;

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(EnhancedTable);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You should define a key for TableRow as a className and then put your hover style right on that class name as an object.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  ...
  tr: {
    background: "#f1f1f1",
    '&:hover': {
       background: "#f00",
    },
  },
  ...
});

return <TableRow className={props.classes.tr} ...>
```

In another example it would be something like this:

```
const styles = {
  tr: {
    background: "#f1f1f1",
    '&:hover': {
      background: "#f00",
    }
  }
};

function Table(props) {
  return (
    <Table>
      <TableRow className={props.classes.tr}>
        {"table row"}
      </TableRow>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Table);
```

Comment: Looking at the MaterialUI API though, it seems the recommended way is to override the CSS API `hover` https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/

Comment: As far as I know, you can only override classes. for styling pseudos you have to select them like this { tr: {'&:hover': { color: 'red' }} }. I took a look at Material-UI documents and actually it was using just like what I mentioned.

Comment: Here is a document about overrides in material-ui. You can override hover styles when you do creatingMuiTheme(). [Document overrides feature](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6687#issuecomment-296676394)

Comment: Thank you for the `&:hover` helper. I've not found one in doc..

Answer (score 9):

By Adding A simple Statement you can customize Hover properties..

```
'&:hover': {
background: "rgb(7, 177, 77, 0.42)",    
             
}
```

So,

```
tableWrapper: {
    overflowX: "auto",
  
  hover: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(7, 177, 77, 0.42)'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking to make some custom hover animations then you can try this style 
This block of code will change the colour of a card on hover.

For more info please check here [Transitions in MUI](https://next.material-ui.com/customization/transitions/)

```
card : {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["background", "background-color"], {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.complex,
    }),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#333",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach

```
const checkBoxStyles = () => ({
  root: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: '#4885FB'
    },
    '&$disabled': {
      color: '#96C9FF'
    },
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#E4F2FF !important'
    }
  },
  checked: {},
  disabled: {
    color: '#96C9FF'
  }
});

const CustomCheckbox = withStyles(checkBoxStyles)(Checkbox);
```

Just note: If you don't specify !important. When the checkbox is 'checked', the on-hover background color get's over-ridden.

I am using material UI version 4

Answer (score 0):

For example, I change the **SVG icon** color when it hovered:

```
     <IconButton>
        <CiteIcon
          sx={{
            '&:hover': {
              '& > path,use': {
                fill: '#f00',
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      </IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        variant="contained"
        sx={{
          bgcolor: "yellow",
          "&:hover": {
            bgcolor: "green",
          },
        }}
      >
        Demo
      </Button>
```