# Changing the background color of a material UI component instantly on click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have managed to use state to change the background color of my buttons on a click event.

Unfortunately, the background color does not change until the mouse is moved away from the button.

How can I make this change appear instantly, as soon as the click event occurs?

Here is my JSX for the button. The buttons inherit their properties from a SideBar component.

```
export default function NavButtons(props) {

const classes = useStyles();

return (
    props.buttons.map(button => {
        return (
            <Button elevation={0} disableRipple
                className={button.id === props.activeMenu? classes.buttonSecondary : classes.button} key={button.id} 
                color={button.id === props.activeMenu ? "default" : "primary"} onClick={() => props.handleClick( button.id)}> 
                {button.icon}<span style={{marginLeft: "0.5rem"}}>{button.label}</span>
            </Button>
        )
    })
)}
```

And the relevant part of the SideBar component:

```
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [clickedButton, setClickedButton] = useState(null);
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState(null);

  const handleActivate = function(key) {
    setClickedButton(key);
    setBgColor(light.palette.secondary.main);
  };
   

    return (
      <div className={classes.sideBar}>
        <NavButtons buttons={Buttons} handleClick={handleActivate} activeMenu={clickedButton} background={bgColor} />
      </div>
    );
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your setState is updating the button's base backgroundColor, but not it's "onHover" color.
Here is an example of manipulating Material UI's hover styling, just add some css onClick:
[MaterialUI Custom Hover Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596070/materialui-custom-hover-style)